# Having trouble displaying JSON objects using Angular

Tags: json, angular

Having an interesting time pulling this `weather_code` object to the page. Any ideas? :-)

[image]

Here's my code:

```
    <div *ngFor="let forecast of this.weatherData?.forecasts | keyvalue">
    {{ forecast.value.hourly[0].weather_code }}
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add the desired behavior, the error code if there's any and the typescript code.

Comment: Hourly is another array so if you need all those values, you can do another *ngFor..

Comment: @JFPicard - I simply want to display weather_code on the page. No error. Just the call being logged in Console.

Comment: just a friendly reminder; in your html you don't have to and shouldn't use  `this.` instead of this.weatherData?.forecasts you can just write weatherData?.forecasts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{{ forecast.value.hourly[0].weather_code }}

Answer (score 2):

where is the forecasts array? If the whole object is the displayed object (in your screenshot) you just have to do `response.forecast['2021-01-25'].hourly[0].weather_code`

Comment: what is array you're trying to iterate. Because in your screenshot there isn't an iterable (array) called forecasts ?

Comment: Trying to go after the Forecast>date>hourly>weather_code

Comment: well, I feel dumb. changed "forecasts" to "forecast" and it works. here is a working snippet: {{ forecast.value.hourly[0].weather_code }}

Comment: question: how do you pull the second item under the forecast array without defining a specific value? These are not working... 
'{{ forecast.value[1].hourly[0].weather_code }}'
'{{ forecast[1].hourly[0].weather_code }}'

Comment: forecast[value].hourly[0].weather_code @Devvvvv